# Square root of an integer has only even digits

Tags: number-theory, ergodic-theory, decimal-expansion

Is there a non-square positive integer $n$, that $\sqrt{n}$ has only even digits in its decimal representation ?

Comment: It's believed not: every irrational algebraic number is conjectured to be normal (and hence its decimal expansion contains all $10$ digits). I don't know if this special case has been solved.

Comment: Out of pure interest, does "normal" mean that every digit appears equally "often"?

Comment: I think for this special case, calculate the probability that a real number has decimal expression with only even digits might be helpful.

Comment: normal number http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number

Comment: @ougao: How will that help?

Answer (score 3):

No such $n$ is known.

If one were found, it would be the biggest shock in Mathematics since, well, maybe since ever; certainly, since Godel's incompleteness results.

No proof is known that such an $n$ does not exist.

Comment: Could you elaborate the connection of this question with Godel's Theorem?
Thanks :)

Comment: The only connection is that Godel's results came as a shock, and finding such an $n$ would be at least as big a shock. The connection is sociological, not mathematical.